# How to control Outlook Add-ins programatically?

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I downloaded an outlook add-in, which after install create the new tab on the ribbon, and create buttons on new tab. I would like to press these buttons without ui interaction.
I tried query installed add-ins, but can not be controlled:

```
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass();
        for ( int c = 1; c < app.COMAddIns.Count; c++ )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( app.COMAddIns.Item( c ).Description );
            if ( app.COMAddIns.Item( c ).Description.StartsWith( "XXX" ) )
            {
                string guid = app.COMAddIns.Item( c ).Guid; // Okay
                object obj = app.COMAddIns.Item( c ).Object; // null
                object parent = app.COMAddIns.Item( c ).Parent; // ApplicaionClass
                string progId = app.COMAddIns.Item( c ).ProgId; // Okay
            }
        }
    }
```

But it is possible, wrong way. Possible query the ribbon control's buttons?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The actions of buttons in ribbons are not publicly available. You can't even programmatically call a click event on the button itself when you are inside the same add-in. (you can call the event handler, but that is just all .NET side without interfering with VSTO / Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

No Office ribbon controls are exposed for the programmatic access.

You can use either [UI Automation API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327(v=vs.110).aspx) or you can use Redemption (I am its author) and its [SafeRibbon](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/SafeRibbon.htm) object (exposed by the [SafeExplorer](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/SafeExplorer.htm).Ribbon property) - it allows to enumerate and execute Outlook ribbon controls:

```
 set sInspector = CreateObject("Redemption.SafeInspector")
 sInspector.Item = Application.ActiveInspector
 set Ribbon = sInspector.Ribbon
 oldActiveTab = Ribbon.ActiveTab 'remember the currently selected tab
 Ribbon.ActiveTab = "Task"
 set Control = Ribbon.Controls("Assign Task")
 Control.Execute
 Ribbon.ActiveTab = oldActiveTab 'restore the active tab
```